# Flutter video_compress and then ffmpeg trim video to 30s fails with endless logs

Tags: flutter, video, ffmpeg, compression

I am trying to make a simple app in Flutter. A user can either take or pick a video and then upload it. However, I wanted to compress the video for storage purposes on firebase storage, and also trim it to only get the first 30 seconds.

I am facing a very puzzling problem. I am able to compress the video, but with the resultant file, FFmpeg fails to trim it and I get endless logs which result in me having to stop the app and re-run. Alternatively, I am able to trim the video, but with the resultant file, I am unable to compress it getting the error:   `Failed to open file '/data/user/0/live.roots.roots/app_flutter/TRIMMED.mp4'. (No such file or directory) PlatformException(error, java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.`

This is my code below:

```js
//! function that controls file compression and trimming
static Future<File> compressFile(File file) async {
    print('[COMPRESSING FILE]');

    String mimeStr = lookupMimeType(file.path);
    var fileType = mimeStr.split('/');

    if (fileType.contains("image")) {
      print('[COMPRESSING FILE] - file is image');
      String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
      String targetPath = '$tempPath/${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.jpg';
      return await compressImageAndGetFile(file, targetPath);
    } else {
      print('[COMPRESSING FILE] - file is video');

      final compressedVideoFile = await compressVideoAndGetFile(file);
      print('[VIDEO FILE COMPRESSED]');
      return await trimVideoGetFile(compressedVideoFile);
    }
  }
  
  
//! function to compress video
static Future<File> compressVideoAndGetFile(File file) async {
    print('[COMPRESSING VIDEO]');

    var result = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
      file.absolute.path,
      quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality,
      deleteOrigin: true,
    );

    print('[COMPRESSED VIDEO TO]: ${result.file.path}');

    return result.file;
  }
  
//! function to trim video
static Future<File> trimVideoGetFile(File file) async {
    print('[TRIMMING VIDEO]');

    Directory appDocumentDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String rawDocumentPath = appDocumentDir.path;
    String outputPath = rawDocumentPath + "/TRIMMED.mp4";

    final newFile = File(outputPath);

    if (await newFile.exists()) {
      await newFile.delete();
    }

    _flutterFFmpeg
        .execute(
            "-ss 00:00:00 -i ${file.path} -to 00:00:30 -c copy $outputPath")
        .then((rt) async {
      print('[TRIMMED VIDEO RESULT] : $rt');
      if (rt == -1) {
        throw Exception("Something went wrong when trimming the video");
      }
    });

    return File(outputPath);
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Video_compress package allows you to trim the duration without the need to FFmpeg.

```
var result = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
  file.absolute.path,
  quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality,
  deleteOrigin: true,
  startTime: 0, // customize start time
  duration: 30, // customize the length
);
```